# How do I go to Design View after directly editing SQL in LibreOffice Base

Tags: ms-access, libreoffice-base

I'm toying with the idea of migrating an office from Access 97 to LibreOffice 5. The problem is that the people in the office use the Designer in Access for Queries. They have made it clear that they won't learn SQL and as such as the IT I have to find a solution.

The issue arises when I do direct SQL in a LibreOffice Base Query. After using raw SQL I can't get the designer to kick back in for the office workers. Access can go between the two without an issue as long as I use proper Access syntax.

Is this a limitation of LibreOffice or am I over looking an option?

Answer (score 1):

I had to untick 'Run SQL Command Directly' and then select 'Switch Design View On/Off' under view.